# Are there plans to use the empty space in the SoundMenu?

Tags: 11.04, indicator-sound

There seems to be roughly 4 lines of space next to the album art. However only 3 are used.

- Song Title
- Artist
- Album

If nothing is planned for the 4th line. I propose that it is used for track time/length. This way you can tell how far along a song is without the need of a scrub bar.

Unrelated, but I feel that the play-lists section should display how many songs are in that play list. Some of my play lists have no songs, and without realising this, it seems like a bug that the songs wont play.

Answer (score 2):

From the [SoundMenu wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SoundMenu):

> Track metadata item
>   If the music player is not running, or if it is running but has no active track, this   item should not be present at all.
>
> If there is an active track, the item should consist of the track or album art on the leading side, and top-aligned next to it, **three rows of text**. If no track or album art is available, it should fall back to a generic track icon. The text should be the track name, artist, and album, one on each line (aligned the same way as the rest of the menu, regardless of what language each string is in).

<sup>Emphasis mine</sup>

There are no plans for a "fourth" row.

Comment: Ok, fair enough. But there sure is space for it.